# How to use variable from one method in another?

Tags: javascript, soap

How to use site variable value from `onreadystatechange` method in soap method?

My code:

```
soap(value) {
  var siteValue = '';
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open('POST', 'URL', true);
  var to_json = require('xmljson').to_json;
  var sr = xyz

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        soapres = xmlhttp.responseText;
        this.soapresponse(soapres);

        to_json(soapres, function(error, data) {
          var a = data['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body']['wss:readResponse']['readReturn']['resultXml']['_'];
          var jsonR = JSON.parse(a);
          var sitee = jsonR.SALFCY; //site
          siteValue = JSON.stringify(sitee);
          alert(siteValue);
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just define it in the upper scope (in the `soap` function). But I can already feel then: why is it `undefined`? So please, read also about async functions and how to return values from them.

Comment: Be careful, an AJAX request is asynchronous.
Also why do you need it inside `soap()`?